# React calling component function outside of the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a functional component:

```
function Tile(props: any) {

  const selectTile = (() => {
    ...
  })

  return (
    <div>
      ...
    </div>
  )
}
```

I then create another functional component which will hold many `tile`s.

```
function Grid(props: any) {

  const selectAllTiles = (() => {
    
  })

  return (
    <div>
      <Tile></Tile>
      <Tile></Tile>
      <Tile></Tile>
    </div>
  )
}
```

My question is, how can I call the `selectTile()` function for each Tile within the `selectAllTiles()` function? What approaches are there?

Comment: Move the function outside the component.

Comment: @Unmitigated The function has to stay inside as it deals with some state.

Comment: Then you cannot call it from another component. Consider making the function accept parts of the state as parameters.

Comment: You can't, and it's not clear why you need to. Maybe you need to [lift the state up](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/sharing-state-between-components)? Give some context.

Comment: @jonrsharpe The selectTile function starts an animation on the Tile. That function has to be called by a component in the Grid component.

Comment: @greekduck just write some code in both funtions so its easier to see what you want to do and also you should say when the funtion get fired like ex: onClick

Answer (score 0):

I would make the parent component keep track of selected tiles, and it will then inform each Tile (through props) if it is selected or not.

If a Tile should be able to "make itself selected", then a function can be passed from the parent into each Tile (also through props) that the Tile can call and which will update the selected tiles collection in the parent.

Updated code:

```
function Tile(props: any) {
  const { isSelected, makeSelected } = props;

  return (
    <div style={{ ... something based on isSelected ... }}>
      <button type="button" onClick={makeSelected}>Select me</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

```
function Grid(props: any) {

  const [isSelected, setIsSelected] = useState<bool[]>([false, false, false]);

  const makeSelected = (index: int) => {
    // ...
    setIsSelected(...);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Tile isSelected={isSelected[0]} makeSelected={() => makeSelected(0)}></Tile>
      <Tile isSelected={isSelected[1]} makeSelected={() => makeSelected(1)}></Tile>
      <Tile isSelected={isSelected[2]} makeSelected={() => makeSelected(2)}></Tile>
    </div>
  )
}
```

This is just an (untested) example, many approaches are possible.

Comment: he/she wants to start an animation in the Tile component. this can be done by using `useEffect(() => { if (isSelected) { /* start animation */ } return () => { /* stop animation */ }}, [isSelected])`

Answer (score -2):

why don't use like this:

```
    function Tile(props: any) {
    
      return (
        <div>
          ...
        </div>
      )
    }
    
   const selectTile = (() => {
        ...
     })
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).